# Function that returns a weighted average from a list of lists of numbers

Tags: haskell, recursion, average

> Write the `weightedAverage :: [[Int]] -> Double` function, that calculates the grades' weighted average.
>
> For example:

`weightedAverage [[3], [5]] == 4.0`

`weightedAverage [[3,3], [5,5]] == 4.0`

`weightedAverage [[1,5], [5,5]] == 4.0`

`weightedAverage [[3,3,3,3], [5,5], [5,5]] == 4.0`

So far, I managed to write a function that returns the average of a list:

```
listAverage :: [Int] -> Double
listAverage [] = 0.0
listAverage x = fromIntegral(sum x)/fromIntegral(length x)
```

I want to implement this in my `weightedAverage` function using the following code:

```
weightedAverage [[]] = 0.0
weightedAverage [x] = listAverage x
weightedAverage (x:xs) = (listAverage x + weightedAverage (xs))/fromIntegral length(x:xs)
```

The problem is that I get an `Ambiguous type variable 't0' arising from a use of 'length'` error along with a `No instance for (Integral (t0 a0 -> Int)) arising from a use of 'fromIntegral'` error. I also think that my recursion is not correctly implemented.

Comment: Hint: concatenate the items in the list of lists.

Comment: / who's the abuser that designed those absolutely dense examples? / the function call syntax in Haskell is `(foo arg)`, not `arg(foo)`.

Comment: as to your subject matter, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The weight of a list is the number of items. It thus means that we can simply concatenate the list of lists and then determine the average, so you can implement this with:

```
weightedAverage :: [[Int]] -> Double
weightedAverage = listAverage . …
```

where `…` is a function `:: [[a]] -> [a]` that converts a list of list of items to a list of these items.

As for the `listAverge`, it might make more sense to work with two accumulators that keep track of the sum and the length respectively, something like:

```
listAverage :: [Int] -> Double
listAverage = go (0 :: Integer) (0 :: Word) . map toInteger
  where go !s !n [] = fromRational (s % toInteger n)
        go s n (x:xs) = …
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. For the record: I used `(concat (x:xs))` in place of the `...`

Comment: @CoderStudent8822: please don't use `(x:xs)`: that would only work for non-empty lists. You can pattern match with `weightedAverage xs = listAverage (concat xs)`, or simply `weightedAverage = listAverage . concat`

Comment: In this *specific* case, the redundant pattern match is semantically okay, since it just replaces a divide by zero error with an incomplete pattern error. But it will also make the code somewhat less efficient, for technical reasons. Then again, this particular code is very inefficient already, so that probably doesn't matter.

Comment: I would use `listAverage = go (0 :: Integer) (0 :: Word) . map toInteger`. That'll get rid of the risk of overflow for lists with length at most `maxBound :: Word` (you could use `Data.Word.Word64` to be more confident). To avoid losing precision with large sums, it'd also be better to write `go !s !n [] = fromRational (s % toInteger n)`.

Comment: @dfeuer the obvious intention of the task is to actually perform the [weighted average calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean), with weights, not just calculate the same result by different means. and if that were done, the loss of precision and the risk of overflow becomes much lower and in the newbie exercises efficiency concerns are tertiary and so  `Integer` can be just used.

Comment: @WillNess, it's very important, when constructing exercises, to make them reflect their intention precisely. Otherwise students will be confused and instructors will be frustrated.

Comment: @dfeuer it does say "**weighted** average"